# How can I deal with wanting a SQL column to allow different types?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, entity-relationship

I have essentially a table that contains a `rowid`, `person_id` (not importane here), `key`, and `value`.  My problem is that my application needs to be able to support different types of `value`s: some int's, some text fields, and some composite types which hold multiple pieces of information.  The only approach I can think of to solve this is to change `value` into `value_table` and `value_id`, where I have different tables for each type of value, and `value_id` is the primary key in the table given by `value_table` of the desired value.

I am new to SQL though, so I want to know if this is a bad idea for some reason I'm not thinking of.  It seems weird to have value_id be a foreign key into more than one table, and it also seems like it would be difficult to write the queries to enable data access (especially since I'm doing this from Django's ORM).

**Edit with more details:**

My application contains user-added fields where the user sets the name of the field (like a map key) and the value, as well as the type of the value.  The value can be anything from a boolean value or an integer to a 10000+ character text field or a composite type made up of multiple SQL primitive types.

I could use JSON in a text field here, but then I can never implement any kind of sorting or filtering by values, which is a requirement.

Comment: I think your column types should generally not change.  If you have this problem, there may be an underlying design issue.  That being said, `TEXT` can support numbers and letters, so you could always cast to a numeric if you needed it.

Comment: a text | varchar type can save string as well as int, float, date etc, however it is string type. You need to convert | cast type if you needed

Comment: seems like you want to use a Key Value store like e.g. Redis instead of an RDBMS here. But one way to store different kinds of values in MySQL would be to wrap your content into JSON Strings, as long as they are only texts and numbers

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've edited the question to provide some more details in response.  I appreciate all of your suggestions very much! If you wouldn't mind, could you also briefly address why my proposal would not be a good idea? It seems like the opinion is unanimous that I shouldn't go the multiple table route, and I'd like to know the reasoning.  Thank you!

Comment: When employing an EAV model, I like to construct a separate table for each data type, so you have one table that stores integer values, one for decimals, one for dates, and one for strings - each with their respective attribute keys.

Comment: On the multiple table idea: You answer your question yourself - Because it's difficult to access the data in plain SQL. You would always need to write some dynamic code that builds your query, something like this `SELECT concat('SELECT whatever FROM ', a.table_name, ' WHERE ...') FROM table a` and then execute that. You are also not able to enforce referential integrity, because a foreign key constraint always needs a single reference table.

Comment: That's true.  I know usually questions like these boil down to "There's probably a design flaw in what you're suggesting", but I can't think of anything better